# Create table with query but it shows me syntax error where the parenthesis are

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

the problem when I am trying to create a new query, it gives me a red error and says syntax error where is the first parenthesis { are and the INT values of (1,1) and (50) with NVARCHAR and also GETDATE() parenthesis and the ID ([ID] ASC)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cart]
{

      [ID] INT IDENTITY (**1**,1) NOT NULL,
      [CLientID] NVARCHAR (**50**) NOT NULL,
      [ProductID] INT NOTNULL,
      [Amount] INT NOTNULL,
      [DatePurchased] DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE**()**,
      [IsInCart] BIT NOTNULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_Purchase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([**ID**] ASC)
}
```

Comment: You have `NOTNULL` all over the place, which isn't valid SQL code.  Use `NOT NULL`, with a space.

Comment: Replace curly brackets `{` with brackets `(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cart] {` should not with curly braces, it should be with parentheses `()`. And `NOTNULL` should be `NOT NULL`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cart] (
  [ID] INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
  [CLientID] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  [ProductID] INT NOT NULL,
  [Amount] INT NOT NULL,
  [DatePurchased] DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
  [IsInCart] BIT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Purchase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=22848baac3243c8e8cdbad9103a16f62)

Comment: thank you so much it worked well for sql server management 2018

Comment: @MohamedElbalam Welcome. I'm glad I was able to help!

Comment: i get another problem for execute another query and gave me

Comment: SELECT TOP 1000 [ID] 
            ,[ClientID]
   ,[ProductID]
   ,[Amount]
   ,[DatePurchased]
   ,[IsInCart]
 FROM [GarageDB].[dbo].[Cart]
 CREATE INDEX ClientIndex
 ON  [GarageDB].[dbo].[Cart][ClientID]

Comment: `CREATE INDEX ClientIndex ON [GarageDB].[dbo].[Cart] ([ClientID])` You need to add paraentheses around the column name i.e., `[ClientID]` here

Comment: sorry, but this one didnt workout for me and all the column names get red line and cant figure it out why i use sql management server 18

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct database name `[GarageDB]`?

Comment: yes i am sure and i have 3 tabels 1- Product

Comment: 2- producttype 3-Cart which has problems when i try to select Top 100 Rows and other 2 tabels are working but not Cart Tabel

Comment: @MohamedElbalam `SELECT TOP 1000 [ID] ,[ClientID] ,[ProductID] ,[Amount] ,[DatePurchased] ,[IsInCart] FROM [GarageDB].[dbo].[Cart]` alone should work

Comment: really thanks for your help and worked after i reduced the Rows from Top 1000 to 50 but i dont know if that was the reason

Comment: SELECT TOP (10) 
        [ID] 
  ,[ClientID] 
  ,[ProductID] 
  ,[Amount] 
  ,[DateParchased] 
  ,[IsInCart]
  
  FROM [GarageDB].[dbo].[Cart] CREATE INDEX ClientIndex ON [GarageDB].[dbo].[Cart] ([ClientID])